# Reproduce a table mock-up in .NET winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I just start with .NET and C# and I have to realize a table from a mock-up.
I'm using winform but I'm stuck with a issue about the table header.

I do not know how to create a header with two rows and 5 columns in on cell.

Here's the mock-up :
[image]

May you explain to me how to realize it?
Thanks a lot !

EDIT: Coul you tell me how put checkboxes in cells too?

EDIT 2 : What I dit.

[image]

The code is almost empty and do not have any connection with the GUI that I want to realize.

Comment: Please include information and code describing what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: The built-in `DataGridView` doesn't offer much flexibility for custom designs like this... maybe you should look at datagrids offered by third-parties.

Comment: @Meta-Knight Oh really?! Damn... What you mean by datagrids offered by third-parties, is that a component?

Comment: Sounds that what you're trying to do is too complex for someone who just started with .net. I would do some reading on advanced data grid techniques. You would have to either write your own grid or control, or get infragistics grid. Your question can't be answered here, therefore I vote to close it.

Comment: @Majestic: I mean commercial winforms controls by companies like DevExpress, Telerik...

Comment: @T.S. Seriously ? Only the fractionnal cell in the table's header and the checkboxes are missing. There is surely a way to do it quickly, no? Edit: I found how to make the column with checkboxes. Only the split cell in the table's header is missing :/

Comment: @T.S. : You're the first guy I meet on this site with a such behavior. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: I don't know what else to say? Meta Knight has 12K reputation, and I, both tell you same thing, and you pressing your agenda. Companies spend millions to develop what seem a simple thing to you. Your question doesn't fit this website policy because it requires research and development. My suggestion is that you talk to project owner and work on getting rid of that sub-header. It is not that valuable. And instead, have 4 simple checkbox columns - `IS-TLS`, `IS-HBG`, etc......

Comment: I understand, but as I said I'm beginner with GUI .NET. And I was thinking it could be done easily. Did no think it was so complex to split a cell.
And I have some constraints about the development, indeed I'm not doing for myself, I'm doing it for my work. So I can not use everything I want such as the third-parties's tools. That's why I asked some help about it... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doable by using the CellPainting event:

```
dgv.CellPainting += dgv_CellPainting;

void dgv_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e) {
  if (e.ColumnIndex > -1 && e.RowIndex == -1) {
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) {
      int totalWidth = e.CellBounds.Width;
      for (int i = 2; i < 5; ++i) {
        totalWidth += dgv.Columns[i].Width;
      }
      Rectangle r = new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Top + 1, 
                                  totalWidth, e.CellBounds.Height - 16);
      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, r);
      TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "IMPORT SITES", SystemFonts.DefaultFont,
                            new Rectangle(r.Left, r.Top, r.Width, r.Height - 4),
                            Color.Black, Color.Empty,
                            TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
      e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Gray, new Rectangle(r.Left - 1, r.Top - 1, r.Width, r.Height));
    }

    if (e.ColumnIndex >= 1 && e.ColumnIndex <= 4) {
      Rectangle r = new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Top + e.CellBounds.Height - 16,
                                  e.CellBounds.Width, 16);
      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, r);

      TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText,
        SystemFonts.DefaultFont, new Rectangle(r.Location, new Size(r.Width, r.Height - 2)),
        Color.Black, Color.Empty, TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
      e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Gray, new Rectangle(r.Left - 1, r.Top - 1, r.Width, r.Height));
    } else {
      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, e.CellBounds);
      TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText,
        SystemFonts.DefaultFont, e.CellBounds, Color.Black, Color.Empty,
        TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
      e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Gray, new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.Left - 1, e.CellBounds.Top,
                                                        e.CellBounds.Width, e.CellBounds.Height - 1));
    }
    e.Handled = true;
  }
}
```

Result (tweak as needed):

[image]

For the check boxes, just use the editor to add the DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn type.

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks a lot !